# Nonlinear behavior of function run time

Tags: c, optimization, timing

I have a function which computes a sum and depending on the result of the sum does a certain task or gives a warning message. I need to run this function millions of times in a particle trajectory simulation (it calculates the time and position dependent force) and noticed that my code was very slow.

This is my MWE:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int foo()
{
    double sum =0;
    double dummy_sum = 0;

    for (size_t i=0; i<40; i++)
    {
        sum+=1e-2; 
        dummy_sum += 1e-2;     
    }

    if (sum>5.) // normally this should not happen
    {
        printf("warning message!\n");
        return(-1);
    }
    else if(sum >0)
    {
       // normal behavior
    }

    return(0);
}

int main()
{
   int fooint;

   for(size_t i=0; i<5e9; i++)
   {
       fooint = foo();
       if(fooint!=0)
       {
           return(fooint);
       }
   }
   return 0;
}
```

I compile with `gcc -Ofast -std=c99 test.c -o test.exe` using gcc version  4.8.5.

In order to find a way to optimize my function I ran `time ./test.exe` which indicated a run time of about 38s on my machine.

When I removed the lines

```
        printf("warning message!\n");
        return(-1);
```

or the line

```
        sum+=1e-2;
```

the run time was reduced to about 6s.

Also when I changed the number of iterations in the function loop to 35 the speed is increased and the run time is 6s. Increasing it to 36 gives a run time of 33s.

I compiled and ran the code on a different machine with the same linux and gcc versions and got similar results (run times were slightly longer as the machine is older).

What may cause this strange behavior?

Comment: how many times is printf called?

Comment: And why are you using doubles in foo() when it would be faster and more accurate with integers?

Comment: @OldProgrammer in the test versions it was never called, that's why I was so surprised at the reduced performance.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker I minimized my original function and forgot to replace the doubles that I need in the final function by integers in the MWE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a GCC bug. Clang optimises your code properly to

```
foo:                                    # @foo
        xor     eax, eax
        ret
main:                                   # @main
        xor     eax, eax
        ret
```

at near-zero run time.

[Live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/XZB5cc)

Answer (score 5):

It is not a strange behavior.
If you remove the lines `printf` and `return(-1)` then the function `foo` is optimized by the compiler and will be just `return(0);` none of the code inside it will be executed, because the result will not change. The same happens if you comment the code `sum+=1e-2;`, the compiler knows that the only possible result for the function is `return(0);`, `sum` is initialized to 0 and never changes.